# Python: Retrieve a file from url and generate data: URI

Tags: python, url-encoding

I've a url to gravatar image as

```
url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0eee0fa5a325a984dab6c1e9c7a1968f?d=retro&s=40"
```

And I want to generate data:URI for it like following in python

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAIAAAADnC86AAAAjklEQVRYhWP0E3dnIAUY9jdiFT9fWE+SOUwkqaYiGHkWs+CSQI5LUuOPGL0jL6gHzGJGYvIxrryLCxCTJkZeUI9aPGoxzQDOshoXwJVHSc3rIy+oB0dZTa32FDHmjLygHnz5GDk+KKmPcekdeUE9OPIxMsDVNiYmj462qweVxUS1q2kBRl5Qj1o8ajHNAABQ3ieujBTqugAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: Please provide your code attempt for this. And explain what is currently not working out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes) and [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import base64
import requests

url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0eee0fa5a325a984dab6c1e9c7a1968f?d=retro&s=40"
response = requests.get(url)
content_type = response.headers["content-type"]
encoded_body = base64.b64encode(response.content)
print("data:{};base64,{}".format(content_type, encoded_body.decode()))
```

Response:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAIAAAADnC86AAAAjklEQVRYhWP0E3dnIAUY9jdiFT9fWE+SOUwkqaYiGHkWs+CSQI5LUuOPGL0jL6gHzGJGYvIxrryLCxCTJkZeUI9aPGoxzQDOshoXwJVHSc3rIy+oB0dZTa32FDHmjLygHnz5GDk+KKmPcekdeUE9OPIxMsDVNiYmj462qweVxUS1q2kBRl5Qj1o8ajHNAABQ3ieujBTqugAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Comment: Showing the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'encodebytes'`

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: Then use https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode instead.

Comment: why are you encoding and then decoding?